# Having a widget_id how can I render the widget itself

Tags: php, wordpress

Assuming I am able to fetch the "widget_id" of a particular widget. How can I then render/display that wiget

```
 e.g. show_widget($widget_id);
```

DETAILS:
I want to able able to add widgets to a sidebar (using appearance -> widgets). Then programmatically I like to able to fetch that widget in that sidebar and display it.

Is there a way I can do this ?

Comment: Widgets don't have IDs. They have class names. What exactly is your question here? If you want to display widgets, you need to look into [Dynamic Sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)

Comment: @maiorano84 I have added more detail to my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `the_widget`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget

You will need the widget class name, not the widget_id